# rtabmap source panel disabled

Tags: ros-kinetic, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

I am working on multi-session mapping with rtabmap. I am following [this](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Multi-Session-Mapping-with-RTAB-Map-Tango) tutorial.  but my source is disabled and even I can't find "File->Open database..." option in my gui. [image] I am using ubuntu 16.04 and ros.

Comment: Which release version of `rtabmap` are you using? You show an Ubuntu screenshot, so did you build the binary yourself (as v.0.21.0 only offers Mac and Windows)? At what step of the tutorial are you failing? Step 3 or later? I can't see where the source is selected in the tutorial.